# what does each field of strm UI mean?

Tags: apache-storm

I want to see performance of each bolt and decide the number of parallelism.

In storm UI there are several fields which is confusing, so would be glad if you can tell me.

1. Capacity(last 10m) - average capacity per one second in last 10 minute of a single executor?
   For example, if Capcity is 1.2, does that mean single executor processed 1.2 messages per second in average?
2. Execute latency and Process latency - Is it average value or value of last processed message?
   and what is the difference between them?
   and what is the difference between them and Capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a great article describing the Storm UI. You can reach it by link: http://www.malinga.me/reading-and-understanding-the-storm-ui-storm-ui-explained/

So, we have that:

- **capacity (last 10m)** – If this is around 1.0, the corresponding Bolt is running as fast as it can, so you may want to increase the Bolt’s parallelism. This is (number executed * average execute latency) / measurement time.
- **Execute latency (ms)** – The average time a Tuple spends in the execute method. The execute method may complete without sending an Ack for the tuple.
- **Process latency (ms)** – The average time it takes to Ack a Tuple after it is first received. Bolts that join, aggregate or batch may not Ack a tuple until a number of other Tuples have been received.

Also, I found that documentation for the Storm UI REST API can be very useful for understanding the fields meaning: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/STORM-UI-REST-API.md